# Format cells that contain formula or hard number

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am new to VBA and I would like some help please.

I want a macro that highlights cells that contain only formula, the ones that contains a hard number, and if possible the ones that contains a formula and a hard number added to the formula:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score -3, accepted):

There is a `HasFormula` test you can run.

You would need to select the range then run the macro or change the `For each cel in Selection` to `For each cel in [A1:B25]` (change `[A1:B25]` to whatever range you want)

```
Sub CheckFormulas()
   Dim cel as Range 
   For each cel in Selection 
     If cel.HasFormula then
       ’Whatever you want to do the formula cell here
     Else
       ’Whatever you want to do to the non formula cell here 
      End if 
    Next cel
End sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [Range.SpecialCells method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.SpecialCells).

- `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstant, xlNumbers)` gives you all constant numbers
  eg `500`
- `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers)` gives you all formulas with numbers as result
  eg `SUM(C8:C13)` or `SUM(C8:C13)+522`

Note that `SpecialCells` throws an error if the specified type of cell is not found. Therefore you need to check this eg. by suppressing the error and checking the set variable for `Nothing`:

```
Dim MyConstantNumbers As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set MyConstantNumbers = Range("A1:A10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstant, xlNumbers)
On Error Goto 0
If Not MyConstantNumbers Is Nothing Then
    'color your cells here
End If
```

Comment: Actually, `SpecialCells` returns a "No Cells Found" error 1004, not `Nothing`, so you have to Catch the error.  It's *really* annoying :(  (And could whoever downvoted please explain *why* they think this answer requires improvement)

Comment: @Chronocidal Of course, you are right! Thank you, I fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

You can select certain Cell Types within a Range with the `SpecialCells` method.  Cells with a Formula are `xlCellTypeFormulas`, and Cells with a "Hard-Coded" Value are `xlCellTypeConstants`

```
Sub ColorCellsByType(Target As Range, FormulaColour As Long, ConstantColour As Long)
    On Error GoTo NoFormula 'Skip line if there is a "no cells" error
    Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Interior.Color = FormulaColour
NoFormula:
    On Error GoTo NoComments 'Skip line if there is a "no cells" error
    Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).Interior.Color = ConstantColour 'Does not include Text values
NoComments:
    On Error GoTo 0 'Show error messages, so you can fix them
End Sub
```

Your "part 3" makes no sense, since `=SUM(C8:C13)+552` is just a regular formula - did you mean a *Function* with a Constant added to it?

Comment: Note that the OP asked for *"contains a hard number"* but `xlCellTypeConstants` will also return cells that contain text. So this will not work as expected.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Updated the Constants line.  I suspect that the only way to manage the "part 3" is cell-by-cell, with a `Split(Cell.Formula, "+")` and checking for items without brackets...

Comment: Actually the OP didn't exactly tell if he wants these 3 to highlight in *different* colors or just the *same* color. If it is the same color it doesn't matter because `Formula + Constant` would be covered by `xlCellTypeFormulas`. Otherwise a loop is needed which would be much more time consuming.